# Allow drag and drop of an element containing an iframe

Tags: html, css, draggable

I'm trying to have a very basic drag and drop. It's working fine by just setting `draggable = "true"`, but doesn't seem to work when the draggable element contains an iframe.

I have searched everywhere and met many complex problems with iframes, but none being about my specific problem.

As you can see, only the area that is not covered by the iframe is draggable, while I would want to drag the whole container.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #A1DB6A;
}
iframe {
    border: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>
<br/>
<span>Only the green handle is draggable, but I want the whole container to be.</span>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
Maybe you can use jquery draggable

Comment: @user3087839 : [sure](https://howtodoinjava.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/use-jquery.gif)... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Problem:

An `iframe` contains a completely separate window from the parent window. When a user interacts with an `iframe`, the parent window no longer receives user events. The browser assumes you want to interact with the contents of the `iframe`, and ignores any `draggable` attributes that may be on a parent of the `iframe`.

## A Workaround:

You could position an invisible element over the `iframe` to prevent the user from interacting with the `iframe` below. Here is an example using an absolute-positioned pseudo-element.

#### Example CSS ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtawvj7z/)):

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #A1DB6A;
    position: relative;/*parent must have positioning*/
}
iframe {
    border: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
/*Cover up the entire element (could be limited to just covering the iframe element)*/
div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This workaround brings with it the obvious side-effect of preventing the user from interacting with the contents of the `iframe`, which is presumably alright in most cases where you want the element to be `draggable`.

If the `iframe` needs to be interacted with, you could make a toggle between draggable and not-draggable, and only apply this CSS when draggable. Otherwise you would need to use JavaScript to interact with the `iframe`, either by `contentWindow` if they satisfy [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), or by [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage), and toggle it on/off based on certain events.

Comment: Awesome. I no longer really need to solve this but was still very cursious about it. I tried to use `pointer-events: none` as a way to prevent the browser to catch pointer events inside the iframe but it seems like it ignores it (on latest Chrome at least). Adding an invisible on top is clever and elegant, and doing so using `:after` is even better as I never found a usage for it personally. Thank you a lot, you'll have the bounty but apparently I need to wait 22hrs to award it.

Comment: @Alexander This is great solution. However in my case I have an `onclick` attribute in the iframe which doesn't get triggered anymore. Do you know why?

Comment: @SouvikRay If the `iframe` has the `onclick` attribute, and it's being covered by the wrapper `div`'s `:after` content, you won't be able to click on the `iframe`, just the wrapper `div`.